# CSS3 - how to force image height / max-height to match the (calculated) width?

Tags: css

How do you match the image height to the calculated ("width: 25%;") image width?

I've tried "height: calc(width);" but that's invalid. Same with "height: calc(width*1.00)"...

In other words, I don't know the user's screen size / browser size, so I'm specifying "img { width: 25%; } to fit 4 images in a row, but if any of them are non-square, it messes up the layout; **how can I force the height not to exceed the width, whatever that width happens to end up being?**

Answer (score 0):

One trick for doing this takes advantage of the fact that when vertical padding is specified as a percentage, it's a percentage of the element's parent's *width*. With that in mind, you can set an element's `height: 0` and `padding-top: 100%` to get a square element, then render your image as a background.

This probably isn't the best way to mark this up, but for demonstration/proof-of-concept purposes it'll do:

```css
.container {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container > div {
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 100%;
  background: url('http://placekitten.com/200');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div><div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div><div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div><div class="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a pure CSS solution but one option is to dynamically set the height `onload`:

```js
function resize(e) {
  e.height = e.width
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/500" class="image" onload="resize(this)" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/300/500" class="image" onload="resize(this)" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/500" class="image" onload="resize(this)" />
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/500/400" class="image" onload="resize(this)" />
</div>
```

This achieves your dynamic height based on width but has a few downsides because it could "flash" briefly, it's not CSS-based and you'll likely want to re-evaluate on resize.